# Python Type Error : While encoding and replacing ? with "space"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

Here is a function in which I am trying to fetch articles from the `<li>` tag using BeautifulSoup python library and encode, replace("?"," ").

```
def getDoxyDonkeyText(testUrl):
 request = urllib.request.urlopen(testUrl)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(request)
 mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":'post-body'})
 posts =[]
 for div in mydivs:
     posts+=map(lambda p:p.text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?"," "), div.findAll("li"))
 return posts

______________________

articleURL = "http://doxydonkey.blogspot.in"
doxyDonkeyPosts = []
doxyDonkeyPosts=getDoxyDonkeyText(articleURL)
_______________________
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
_________________________
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-cafa01352f7e> in <module>()
      1 doxyDonkeyPosts = []
      2 for link in links:
----> 3     doxyDonkeyPosts+=getDoxyDonkeyText(link)

<ipython-input-34-d5693b21e538> in getDoxyDonkeyText(testUrl)
      6     posts =[]
      7     for div in mydivs:
----> 8         posts+=map(lambda p:p.text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?"," "), div.findAll("li"))
      9     return posts

<ipython-input-34-d5693b21e538> in <lambda>(p)
      6     posts =[]
      7     for div in mydivs:
----> 8         posts+=map(lambda p:p.text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?"," "), div.findAll("li"))
      9     return posts

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
_____________
```

The cause of the error and a workaround would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`str.encode()` will return byte like object on which replace with str will give you an error. you need to provide byte replacement. like `(b'"?", b" ")`

This is simplified version.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getDoxyDonkeyText(testUrl):
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(testUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request, 'html.parser')
    mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":'post-body'})
    posts =[]
    for div in mydivs:
        for li in div.find_all("li"):
            posts.append(
                li.text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace(b"?", b" ")
            )
            # if you want string
            posts.append(
                li.text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').decode().replace("?", " ")
            )
    return posts


articleURL = "http://doxydonkey.blogspot.in"
doxyDonkeyPosts=getDoxyDonkeyText(articleURL)
print(doxyDonkeyPosts)
```

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: @josealex: try now.

Comment: Impeccable! Thanks buddy

Comment: You can accept the answer if this solved your question.